# Rails Resuce, making Information Available in the Switch Rescue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, exception, ioexception, raise

I have the following:

```
class MailingJob < Struct.new(:mailing_id)

  class MissingInfo < ArgumentError; end

  def perform
   ....

    begin
      ......
          raise MissingInfo, "Not found", message_all, @message_from if @message_reply.length == 0
      ......    
    rescue MissingInfo => reason, message_all, message_from
      UserMailer.delay.incoming_mails_error_notification(reason, message_all, message_from)
    end

  end
```

The problem I'm having here is that in my resuce, I need access to several of the vars in the begin block, so I'm trying to pass them when I call RAISE. That doesn't appear to be working. Also, these variables are consisten across many raises, so it really fills up the page.

Is there a way to make these variable accessible in the resuce without having to define them in the raise?

If not, how do I use raise to pass them to the rescue? The above errors with:

```
SyntaxError (/Users/xxxxx/Sites/xxxxxxx/lib/mailing_job.rb:117: syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting kTHEN or ':' or '\n' or ';'
    rescue MissingInfo => reason, message_all, message_from
                                 ^
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The `rescue` keyword just captures the error object. You need to capture these values inside an exception object:

```
class MissingInfo < ArgumentError
   attr_accessor :messages
   def initialize(messages = {})
     self.messages = messages
   end
end

begin
  raise MissingInfo.new(:all => message_all, :from => message_from, :reason => reason)
rescue MissingInfo => missing_info
  puts missing_info.messages[:all]
end
```

**BUT** This is an abuse of error handling. It's usually better to use begin and raise for real errors, errors which you do not expect. MissingInfo sounds like handling user input. You can expect user input to have missing data. Do normal checks for that. Try to think of the behavior you are really trying to convey.

Comment: Interesting but message is defined in being. so setting it before hand is a problem no?

Comment: Also, NoMethodError (undefined method `attr_accessible' for MailingJob::MissingInfo:Class):

Comment: Also, tried, MissingInfo < RuntimeError... that gets the same undefined method `attr_accessible' for MailingJob::MissingInfo:Class

Comment: woops, its `attr_accessor`, sorry my bad. Answered a question about attr_accessible a few moments before that... :)